# Does anyone know the name of this manhwa about a guy who would decide people’s deaths in his dreams with their photos?

Tags: story-identification, manga

So a long time ago I read this manhwa where a guy who was getting bullied in school would take sleeping pills to go to sleep, and when he falls asleep, he would dream about this place that had long halls full of framed pictures of people he knew(?) and he would write something on the back of their pictures like ex: the time of death and way they die or something. Then when he would wake up, the death would occur to the person whose death he wrote on the back of their photo. I don’t think I ever finished it so I don’t know what happened after that. Does anyone know this manhwa/webcomic?